# How to set the text color in a QMessageBox in C++

Tags: c++, css, qt5, stylesheet

Currently, the text in my application while using the QMessageBox text is a light grey and hard to read. To fix this, I tried to make the text black. I put the following in my style sheet to no avail. I also entered the following C++ code, but I rather use my stylesheet.

```
ExceptionDisplay
{
    color: Black;
}

class ExceptionDisplay : public std::exception
{
public:
    void ErrorMessageBox(QString methodName)
    {
      QMessageBox errorMsgBox;
      ...
      errorMsgBox.setStyleSheet("color: Black");
    }
}
```

I would like to use my stylesheet rather than putting it in code. What do I need to do to accomplish this? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Could possibly be not high enough priority. Try putting 'color: Black ! important'

Comment: before i edit this post i just want to be clear what does this have to do with the C++ language or exceptions?

Comment: also, CSS uses tags or, err, class types as in header{ } and that style refers to the <header></header> html tag, same with p1{} and <p1></p1>. I dont think you have a html tag of <ExceptionDisplay></ExceptionDisplay> perhaps this tutorial cpuld be of use https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: I figured out how to set the text in code. I Have a class for handling all of my exceptions call ExceptionDisplay. In it I have a method ErrorMessageBox, which takes a string, as follows:
      void ErrorMessageBox(QString methodName)
    {
        QMessageBox errorMsgBox;
        ...
        errorMsgBox.setStyleSheet("color: Black");
    }
This works, but I would have rather used my style sheet.

Comment: your class isnt a UI object is it? Does it inherit from a widget?

Comment: The class is an exception:
    class ExceptionDisplay : public std::exception

Comment: the QMessageBox is its own widget, and it has its own class type of QMessageBox in CSS. I'm glad you got it fixed. In the future please add the qt tag and provide a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: Thank you @johnathan! Sorry I didn't include everything at the beginning. This was my first time to ask for help. In the future, I will be much more explicit. Thanks again.